# How to avoid warning for signed electron app for Windows?

Tags: windows, electron, certificate, signing

I have designed an electron app. I sign it on CI with certificate from [www.digicert.com](https://www.digicert.com/). But when users try to install it, they get a warning
"Windows protected your PC. Windows Defender SmartScreen prevented an unrecognized app from starting. Running this app might put your PC at risk." (see the [dialog with the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfWww.png)).

I also tried to to create the app without signing it and the only difference between signed and unsigned apps is the name of the company in the warning (with or without the name).

How can I fix this behavior to prevent this warning from being shown to the user? Maybe using another certificate?

Could you, please give me a recipe on how to sign electron apps for Windows?

Comment: *"I tried to off sing of app"* - Er, you tried what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.digicert.com/ms-smartscreen-application-reputation/

> However, a warning appears if the software has been signed with a regular code signing certificate where the author or publisher has not yet established a reputation of trust. (Only Authenticode Certificates issued by a CA that is a member of the Windows Root Certificate Program can establish reputation.) As the software or its publisher gains a better reputation, the likelihood of a warning diminishes. Reputation for unsigned software is based on fingerprints while reputation based on signed software is based on the associated code signing certificate and the reputation of the CA that issued the code signing certificate.

This is something you cannot control as an application since smartscreen will evalutate based on `reputation`.